# EncodeParameters deinterlace bmp

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a way to take in a 32 bit bitmap and save it again however deinterlacing the frames. When the image is taken two fields are visible but only the last one is necessary. Is this possible to do using EncoderParameters. This is what I've tried so far:

```
using (Image source = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Martin vanPutten\Desktop\test.bmp"))
        {
            ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().First(c => c.MimeType == "image/bmp");

            EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters(3);
            parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
            parameters.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.ScanMethod, (int)EncoderValue.LastFrame);
            parameters.Param[2] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.RenderMethod, (int)EncoderValue.RenderNonProgressive);

            source.Save(@"C:\Users\Martin vanPutten\Desktop\test2.bmp", codec, parameters);
        }
```

Is there another way to do this? All I need to do is remove the second overlapping frame in an image.

Quick update, its not that it has two frames, but 2 fields in 1 frame.

Comment: This looks like a fine way to do this. In which way do you want an alternative solution to differ? For example, do you need it in memory instead?

Comment: This way isn't currently working, I figured I did something wrong... I have an image of an ipod on a timer and you can see the miliseconds count but the 0 and the 1 are merged... the idea is to pull the image in and then save it with only the frame with the 0.

Comment: BMP files support only a single image (or frame).  Are you sure you don't have a single image with the "0" and "1" merged?

Comment: That must be what I have then... I just confirmed my frame count by grabbing the framedimensionlist... if this is the case... is this possible to do with 32 bit bmp's?

Comment: The BMP encoder has no such capability.  I seriously doubt that any of them do.